# Pass variable in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Im wondering how I can set some variables in my controller, and then be able to access them in my model and a behaviour for that model.

I have tried the below, but with no luck:
in controller: $this->Model->data['foo']="bar"; 
in behaviour: $Model->data['foo'];

Grateful for any help!

Comment: It depends on what you do in between. `Model::$data` is a heavily used variable that probably got overwritten before the Behavior was invoked. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to pass data is through user-defined functions in your model.

For example,

```
$flag = $this->Model->checkIntegrity($this->data);
```

In the Model,

```
function checkIntegrity($data) {
    ...
}
```

You could also pass them in as a reference if you wish to make direct changes to the data:

```
function checkIntegrity(&$data) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data you're trying to pass around. If it's model/behavior settings you could use class properties. Example:

In model or behavior:

```
public $custom_variable = null; // or other default value
```

In controller:

```
$this->Model->custom_variable = 'new value';
```

or

```
$this->Behavior->custom_variable = 'new value';
```